# Metal best practices - changing renderPipelineDescriptor during render

Tags: ios, swift, ios9, metal

During my rendering pipeline i would like to user a few shaders and in some cases modify parameters on the MTLRenderPipelineDescriptor object (for example, change blending functions).

As i see it, i have 2 options:

1. Create and precompile one MTLRenderPipelineState for each combination of parameters (vertex shader, fragment shader, blending, etc).I can have many such state objects because there could be many combinations.
2. Create and compile new MTLRenderPipelineState objects during the rendering process.

Which of the options would be better? Are there any other options i am missing.

Comment: definitely not #2 because you don't want any non-transient Metal object (such as states) to be created every time you are rendering. see [my post](http://mhorga.org/2016/02/29/using-metalkit-part-7.html) on this topic.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For *best-practice* (and best performance), you should follow your *Option 1*.

In the [*Transient and Non-transient Objects in Metal*](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Miscellaneous/Conceptual/MetalProgrammingGuide/Cmd-Submiss/Cmd-Submiss.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014221-CH3-SW2) section, The *Metal Programming Guide* is quite clear about which objects should be considered transient or non-transient, and that non-transient objects should be cached and reused.

For the `MTLRenderPipelineState` object in particular, here's what the guide has to say in the [*Creating a Render Pipeline State*](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Miscellaneous/Conceptual/MetalProgrammingGuide/Render-Ctx/Render-Ctx.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014221-CH7-SW37) section:

> A render pipeline state object is a long-lived persistent object that
>   can be created outside of a render command encoder, cached in advance,
>   and reused across several render command encoders. When describing the
>   same set of graphics state, reusing a previously created render
>   pipeline state object may avoid expensive operations that re-evaluate
>   and translate the specified state to GPU commands.

Answer (score 1):

Option #1 is better.

With option #2 it isn't clear if you are thinking of discarding the object at the end of each rendering pass or if you would cache it and use it next time you require that permutation.

The former would be a very bad idea but the latter would be a good enough, pragmatic approach if the number of possible permutations your code has to support is very large, but the number you are actually going to use in any given run is relatively small and you have no easy way of determining it in advance. This sort of scenario isn't ideal, but can easily be imagined in the context of writing engine-level code which has to expose a lot of flexibility to project-level code.