# Is there a better way to optimize Metal compute shaders that operate on the same texture in series?

Tags: ios, metal, metalkit

I am using Metal to process video frames in real time. At a high level, my code is structured as follows:

1. Obtain a video texture
2. Create a command buffer
3. Encode a number of compute shaders in series, each with its own command encoder created from the command buffer in (2). Each shader operates on the texture in (1) – reading from it, performing some calculation, and writing back to it (via `read_write` access).
4. Commit the command buffer

When profiling this setup, I noticed that the actual computations take up a very small proportion of the GPU work. The vast majority is taken up by the "synchronization" category on shader lines that read from or write to the texture:

[image].

The [Metal documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/analyzing-the-performance-of-your-metal-app) seems to imply that this is a product of processing large textures:

> Large textures: Indicated by high synchronization time when profiling
> your fragment shader. The per-line profiling result shows a high
> percentage of time in wait memory.

That makes sense, but I can't reduce the size of my textures since I'm processing 4k video at full resolution. As an experiment, I tried making one massive shader that takes all necessary the input textures and buffers and performs all the computations in one function. Performance was greatly improved, and the total synchronization cost was reduced as expected. Of course, this makes a lot of sense – it seems much better to read once at the start of processing and write once at the end. However, it is much more convenient (from the perspective of the rest of the code) to treat each compute step as its own compute kernel. That way, I can easily add or remove steps as necessary, and I don't have a ton of largely unrelated parameters in my kernel function.

Is there another way I can avoid this synchronization overhead without creating one massive compute kernel? It seems like there should be some way to allow Metal to elide (or at least optimize) a write immediately followed by a read from the same texture within the same command buffer. I thought that coalescing these shaders to use one encoder might help; however, I don't think I can do this – each shader has varying auxiliary input textures or buffers. Moreover, I saw in the debug tools that Metal seems to be coalescing these encoders automatically.

Comment: I don't suppose fooling with the "pipeline state" would help?  (ie as here for example https://stackoverflow.com/a/36039222/294884 )

Comment: I don't believe so. I already reuse pipeline states as recommended.

Comment: Have you tried moving at least some of the stuff to fragment shaders or tile pipelines?

Comment: I would also watch this video https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2021/10153/

Comment: @Spo1ler What kinds of work would be a candidate for fragment shaders or tile shading? I am not overly familiar. All of my compute shaders are image processing  operations applied to a MTLTexture backed by a CVPixelBuffer, which is then written to a file – no rendering to the screen involved. My impression was that compute shaders are the preferred way to do this.

Edit: didn't see the link you posted until after I commented – looks like it might answer some of my questions. I will watch it.

Comment: Fragment shaders are not about rendering to the screen. It's a long explanation and the video does a good job of explaining it, but fragment shaders have a lot of advantages, such as not having to store each write back to memory every time you do it, and also they can utilize framebuffer compression on the right hardware.

Comment: Thank you! That video seems to clear up a lot of my concerns – I wish I had come across it earlier. Just to confirm my understanding, is the following correct? The synchronization overhead I observed in my original question is caused by the memory coherency guarantees and global sync points mentioned around 5:40 in the video you linked. To prevent this, I should convert my per-pixel compute kernels to fragments.